# Visual Studio Code - Interactive window: changing the environment does not work even with jupyter installed

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, anaconda, jupyter

My issue is like this one: [How do you change environment of Python Interactive on Vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485485/how-do-you-change-environment-of-python-interactive-on-vscode), but the solution provided does not seem to work for me.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10, using Visual Studio Code 1.53.2 installed from the snap store.

To debug this, I recreated my environment from scratch using conda:

```
name: mytrips

channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge

dependencies:
  - python=3.8.*
  - pip

  - numpy==1.19.*
  - pandas==1.2.*
  - cartopy==0.18.*
  - jupyterlab
```

(I've put `jupyterlab` there so that should have all the dependencies required for the interactive window).

On the lower left, the interpreter is correctly set to the environment "mytrips".
I'm using a test script that contains only the following two lines:

```py
import cartopy


print(cartopy.__version__)
```

When I right click and select "Run python file in terminal", this is what (correctly) happens:

```
source /home/rick/anaconda3/bin/activate
(base) rick@linux:~/Documents/src/My trips$ source /home/rick/anaconda3/bin/activate
(base) rick@linux:~/Documents/src/My trips$ conda activate mytrips
(mytrips) rick@linux:~/Documents/src/My trips$ /home/rick/anaconda3/envs/mytrips/bin/python "/home/rick/Documents/src/My trips/test.py"
0.18.0
```

So you can see here that `cartopy` is imported correctly.

When I hit shift+Enter, or right-click and select to run the current file in the interactive window, it returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cartopy'` because it's using python from the base conda environment.
**Problem 1: I have jupyter in my environment but it behaves as if it's not detected.**

Then, when I click on the top-right corner in the interactive window and select the `mytrips` environment, the Interactive Window prints this as if it has just changed environment:

```
Started 'Python 3' kernel
Python 3.8.6 (default, Sep 25 2020, 09:36:53) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.20.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

But still can't import `cartopy`, and if I check in the Interactive Window what executable it is now using, the result is:

```
import sys
sys.executable
'usr/bin/python3'
```

So that's **problem 2: the Interactive Window does not actually change my environment.**

And just for confirmation, here's proof that the environment has `jupyter` and `cartopy`:

```
(mytrips) rick@linux:~/Documents/src/My trips$ conda list | grep jupyter
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0  
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py38h06a4308_0  
jupyterlab                2.2.6                      py_0  
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0
```

```
(mytrips) rick@linux:~/Documents/src/My trips$ conda list | grep ipython
ipython                   7.20.0           py38hb070fc8_1  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
```

```
(mytrips) rick@linux:~/Documents/src/My trips$ conda list | grep cartopy
cartopy                   0.18.0           py38h0d9ca2b_1
```

Any hints on what's going on?

Comment: Hey Riccardo. I actually work on this extension. I might be able to help debug. Here is the first steps to take:
1. Change the setting Jupyter->Logging->Level to 'debug'
2. Re-run starting up an interactive window with the environment that you want
3. Copy out what is in the Jupyter tab of the VS Code output window
4. Save all that output to a file and attach it to a comment here.

That has our debug output and I can take a look.

Comment: Hi @IanHuff , thanks for the help!

I set the setting to be "jupyter.logging.level": "debug", quit and restarted VSCode, and ran the test file in an interactive window, but it doesn't seem that there's any more output: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Tt92aMQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a recent problem with already a couple of Issues on VSCode-Jupyter github. The main thread is the link below. I also commented my workaround in this link.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4831